# What is the maximum amount of items you can have in your inventory in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I just had a thought.
If I can make one Shulker Box and put a Shulker box in it with a Shulker box in it with a Shulker box in it **repeat as many times as you want to**, how much could I fit in my inventory? I think I can do infinite, just as long as it doesn't take up a lot of memory.

Answer (score 3):

If you *could* put shulker boxes inside each other, you could actually have an infinite amount of items inside one shulker box, as long as you have loaded shulker boxes inside each other.

Now here we are going to solve how many items you *can* actually fit into one inventory.

There are **36 inventory slots** with **one available slot** for shields, arrows, maps, totems of undying, etc., and **4 slots for armour**. First, lets add up the armour and shield slots. That bring us up to **5 items**. Now, if we fill a shulker box up with items, we can fit up to **27 slots, with 1728 items**. Because there are **36 spaces in your inventory**, we have to multiply the amount of items in the shulker boxes by 36. By doing that, we can get **62,208 items**. If we include the shulker boxes themselves, we can fit up to **62,244 items** and then finally we can add the remaining 5 slots from shields and armour. This totals up to a grand total of ***62,249 items that you can fit into your inventory at one time***.

Note: I'm not adding a shulker box into the off-hand because you are playing minecraft bedrock edition, but if you do want to add a shulker box into your off-hand, you can get up to another 1729 including the extra shulker box. This leads to another grand total of **63,978 items**.

Comment: I edited a typo in one of the numbers and a few of the sums which were off by 2, hope you don't mind. You could mention that 1728 = 27 slots times 64 items (1 stack), it might not be obvious for everybody

Comment: Would you count holding an ender chest in your inventory, full of shulker boxes full of iron blocks, that can then be crafted into 81 times more nuggets than blocks? You can hold 139968 iron nuggets in a single shulker box if you use the crafting trick. multiply that by 27, and you get 3779136 items in an ender chest.

Comment: An interesting addendum to your amazing answer: You can put shulker boxes in the 2x2 crafting grid, giving another 6912 items, but I doubt that counts as it is not in the inventory.

Answer (score 0):

I’m coming from Java edition, but I’m pretty sure the game locks you out from doing just that, but assuming you could, I’m also curious how much you could fit before running out of memory.

Afaik Minecraft stores NBT data as a dictionary, and since you’re using Bedrock, that’s using C++ which is a good bit more memory efficient.

Let’s say the average length of an item name is roughly 10 characters, and every item name is preceded by “minecraft:”. This means that the name field is, as a very rough estimate, 21 bytes plus 8 bytes for the pointer on the stack. Then I’m pretty sure the Count is stored as a Short, which is 2 bytes, meaning 1 stack of items with no tags or other NBT is about 31 ish bytes. C++ probably also has to store a pointer for each item so that totals as 39 bytes. If you’re looking for a quick answer then this multiplied out would be about 25.6 million items able to be stored in a Gigabyte.

I’m not saying this is anywhere close to the answer but that’s probably within an order of magnitude

Comment: There's also damage values, NBT data, lots of other random entries, etc. for each item